# Change Preferred Language in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio

When you first install Visual Studio it asks you what your preferred language is and I chose VB. I am now becoming more of a C# guy, but everytime I want to go create a new project. I have to click Other Languages>Visual C#. Is there any way to not have to go through that process. I have seen other people in videos have it like this and I cant seem to find a setting for it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tools** -> **Import and Export Settings...** -> **Reset all Settings**.  Then select C# when asked.

Note that this will likely remove some of your other IDE settings.

Comment: Thanks exactly the way I wanted it!